# Next.js & RTK Query - Check for user authentication on every page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, rtk-query

I'm using RTK Query with Next.js, and I want to check if the user is logged in or not to change the header layout and header text and potentially other things, how should I do that without using `getInitialProps`?

Next.js is not recommending using `getInitialProps` as it's not ideal for performance, however, the recommended method which is `getServerSideProps` does not work on the `_app.tsx` level.

I was thinking of using `NextAuth`, but I'm not sure how to do that while using `RTK Query`, and I couldn't find any example.

If someone can point me in the right direction or the best workflow to authenticate users on every page on Next.js with RTK Query it would be great.

Comment: Why can't you use getInitialProp?  https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

Comment: @evandwight Because it's not recommended anymore by Next.js ...

`Adding a custom getInitialProps in your App will disable Automatic Static Optimization in pages without Static Generation.`

Comment: Noob question: isn't automatic static generation incompatible with generating user specific header text?

Comment: @evandwight Depends on how you layout your app.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get if the user is authenticated or not, the user makes a request to an endpoint and in next.js you can define this in `api` directory where you structure your rest-api code.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const authApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "authApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:300/",
  }),
  // builder is an object that has mutation and query
  endpoints: (builder) => {
    console.log("builder", builder);
    return {
      // we are making post that is wht it is mutation. otherwise it would be query
      fetchUser: builder.query({
         query:()=> "/api/user"
      }),
 ....

 export const {usefetchUserQuery,otherQueriesOrMutations} = authenticationApi;
```

then register this in `store.js`

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    // assuming you already set the slices of the app
     auth: authReducer,
    [authenticationApi.reducerPath]: contactsApi.reducer,
  },
  // userAPI is the middleware that we hook in store which enables caching, invalidation, polling, and other useful features of `rtk-query`
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(authenticationApi.middleware),
});
```

In `api/user` based on your authentication logic, return if user or not. If you use `next-auth`

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/client"

export default async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req })
   ... 
  res.sned(true)
}
```

I am assuming you already set the authentication logic. or maybe you have token-based authentication

```
   const token = req ? req.cookies?.token : null;
   res.send(token)
```

Basically this will be your central point to check the user.

Since you need the user for the header component, inside `Header` component's `useEffect` you can dispatch an action to check if the user authenticated. or you can set up [SessionProvider](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#sessionprovider) so that you can `useSession` hook in header component

```
  // signIn for signing click, signOut is for signing out click
   import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react"

   const { data: session, status } = useSession()
   const loading = status === 'loading'
```

If you want to fetch the user from server-side props, you have to prop drill the user prop to the header component. Depending on how you set up your redux application, with [next-redux-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-redux-wrapper) or not, the dispatching action will be different

Comment: I don't think that will work, or maybe I can't wrap my head around it, but I need to be able to check the user logged in status server-side, that's why I was thinking of "getInitialProps", but Next.js advise against it, and according to the docs, the server-side check must happen on a "page" component level, NOT on a regular component level.
So, how exactly should I check the user logged-in status on every page without repeating my code on every page component.
If you have a working example using RTT-Query with or without next-auth it would be great.

Comment: @Ruby authentication can be done millions of ways. Since you use rtk, i explained a general set up. But if you put the next-auth in the picture, next-auth has tons of methods. You can use next-auth for authentication and rtk for building and maintatining api

Comment: I don't think you read my comment carefully, I said I need a working example with or without next-auth, I'm just looking for a complete working example.